# Photon user objects destroyed on disconnect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, photon, disconnect

I want to stop photon from destroying the user instantiated gameobjects when the user disconnects so that on reconnect they are still there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more details, so the community could help you and answer your question. Please find the article about asking good questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should try instantiating your gameObjects with:

```
PhotonNetwork.InstantiateSceneObject()
```

This way they won't be destroyed.
You can read more about Photon Instantiation [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/zh-cn/pun/v1/gameplay/instantiation)